# How to set configuration where start page is is a subfolder of root

Tags: configuration, nginx

I have successfully installed nginx. I wish to set the start page of my static website, but the start page is not in the root, but in a subfolder called /en
I tried changing the directive in the config file from
index index.html index.htm;
to
/en/index /en/index.html /en/index.htm;

But nginx threw an error when I tried to reload.

Please help me to change the configuration for the start page one level down in the folder structure.

regards
Jimmy

Comment: When I browse to http://192.168.100.129:81 (just running locally) I get the nginx welcome page. When I browse to http://192.168.100.129:81/en I get the index.html page which I want as my landing page. I want to change the configuration to take me to my index.html page under the /en folder when I browse to When I browse to http://192.168.100.129:8i

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to have your webserver config redirect to the /en directory when you hit www.domain.com:

```
server {
  listen <ip-address>;
  server_name domain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://www.domain.com/en/$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

The above may need to be tweaked (e.g. if you don't want to hold on to the request URI).